# Exporting Notes for Contacts Resulting in Incomplete Notes

Tags: contacts, export

So I'm new to using CiviCRM and I'm having some difficulty exporting my contacts properly. More specifically, I am unable to export all of the notes from a few of the contacts. I have been using the Select Fields for Export option and have selected several fields, including the Notes field. When I open the resulting CSV file I have found that only a few of the notes were actually exported. The notes are quite extensive (the person who made them originally wrote mini-novels on each contact) and, from what I have read online, this causes a problem. From what I have gathered it looks like the notes cut off when they reach some sort of a character limit. My question is: is there a way to export all of the notes, in their entirety, without loss of information, or is there some sort of a "hidden" character limit for fields?

[image: Screenshot of one of the notes created by the original user.]

There are 29 more for this contact alone.

I've blurred the actual text for confidentiality.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so by using API directly. cf. `https://yourdomain.org/civicrm/api/explorer` and use `Entity = Note` and `Action = get`

If you want to have it in a csv format, you could use the command line script provided in CiviCRM `bin/csv/export.php`

You will find the information about this script here : https://civicrm.org/blog/xavier/new-tools-to-automate-the-configuration-and-stagingproduction-migration

So you should be able to do what you want we a command line like :

```
php /full/path/to/bin/csv/export.php -u"user" -p"password" -s"yourdomain.org" Note > notes.csv
```